# Where I can find the Magento2 reinforcement exercises?

Tags: magento2

I’m taking the magento2 boot camp and I’m watching the supplied videos.
However, I’m struggling to find any reinforcement exercise guide mentioned for example in 1.3.1 or 1.5.1, neither I’m able to find what exercise I should do. Was only able to find the exercise solutions. Wrote to support but still no answer

Anyone knows where I should find it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found it but in case someone else is looking: In the "My courses" section underneath the course you are taking, you're bound to see a button with a small stack sign that says "x modules" (x being the number of modules in your course).

It is this button and when you click on it, you end up seeing a long list with all the modules. Scroll quite a bit down the list until you find the "Exercise Guide & Solutions" thing. Click on it and it opens up and you'll find your exercises and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. It can be found if you go to the list of units for the course. It’s # 15 on the list.
[image]